# "numpy.float 64" object is not callable error in tkinter. How can I solve this error?

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, events, floating-point

I am trying to extract the masked region pixel coordinates of an image put in a label in tkinter GUI. However first time I run the code, it works fine but when I run it second time it throws me an error. Here is my code and I also added my exception below. Thank you for reading. Have a nice day!

```
#Mask image and retrieve coordinates of the mask
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import PIL.Image as imge
import PIL.ImageTk as imtk

curPth = sys.path[0]
imgPth = curPth+'/Img_GUI.png'
tmpPth = curPth+'/temp.png'

ev = None
thikness = 25



def click(event):
    global ev, back,  cropped, y,Y, x,X, mask, out
    if ev == None:
        ev = event
        return None

    im = cv2.imread(imgPth)
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(im.copy()*0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.line(mask, pt1=(ev.x, ev.y), pt2=(event.x, event.y),
    color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=thikness)
    mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    out = im.copy()
    out[np.where(mask == 0)] = 255

    out = cv2.cvtColor(out, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    back = imtk.PhotoImage(image=imge.fromarray(out))
    lbl.config(image=back)

    x, X = min(ev.x, event.x)-thikness//2, max(ev.x, event.x)+thikness//2
    y, Y = min(ev.y, event.y)-thikness//2, max(ev.y, event.y)+thikness//2
    cropped = mask[y:Y, x:X]

    print(cropped, cropped.shape)

    ev = event
    print(x, y, X, Y)


root = Tk()
back = PhotoImage(file=imgPth)
lbl = Label(root, image=back)
lbl.place(x=0, y=0)
root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: click(event))
root.mainloop()
```

My error looks like this

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\aravi\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
File "<ipython-input-7-e0e6e9918250>", line 53, in <lambda>
  root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: click(event))
File "<ipython-input-7-e0e6e9918250>", line 39, in click
  x, X = min(ev.x, event.x)-thikness//2, max(ev.x, event.x)+thikness//2
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error using your code.  I suspect that you have assigned `min` or `max` a `numpy.float64` object somewhere else in your original code.

Comment: Hi yes. It was very stupid of me I couldn't find it and I never thought of it. Yes I have used another min and max for a np.array in my other cell in jupyter notebook so its causing the issue. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My specific mistake is caused by me using the min, max in another cell of a jupyter notebook, causing this code to be confused about which min value to chose from, as @acw1668 said in the comments. However, as explained in this [article](https://www.statology.org/typeerror-numpy-float64-object-is-not-callable/), this error can also arise if the arithmetic operators are not used correctly.